# How to solve these black apps

Tags: 21.10

Perhaps it is very easy to fix but I haven´t been able to do it yet. So far, two applications only show a black screen when I open them:
[The black box which should be NordPass asking for the master password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28Owi.png)
NordPass does not even have a title
[Spotify, with a title bar, but no content is loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5vgn.png)

Weird thing is, stuff like Visual Studio Code, Android Studio and Chrome work just fine!
If anyone knows a solution to this or wants me to try something, let me know :)

Update: I've managed to get Spotify working by using the [Debian instructions](https://www.spotify.com/us/download/linux/) instead of Snap. But no solution for NordPass yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spotify gives black screen mostly because it renders GPU features.So, once you disable it, Spotify works fine for almost everyone.

Here's how you can do it:

- Open your terminal window
- Run the command: `spotify --disable-gpu`

Once done, you shall be able to run Spotify successfully.

***Information source: Spotify community forum***

Let us know if this works out for you or not.

Cheers,
Manu

Comment: Spot on! It was indeed a graphics (driver) issue. Changed that and everything is smooth. Thank you!